# How-to-add-23-24-25 behind-22 without adding more children?

Tags: tikz-qtree

```
%%%use PDFLATEX
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}




\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)
-- +(14pt,0)
|- (\tikzchildnode)}}}






\begin{document}\large




\vspace{1cm}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=100pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}


\Tree
[.\node(yawei){yawei};
 [.\node(muqiu){muqiu}; ]
 ]


 \begin{scope}[every node/.style={align=center, anchor=center, font=\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries,rectangle,draw,text width=1.4cm,}]
 \node[above= 2mm of muqiu ] (thenode) {22};
 \node[at =(thenode-|yawei)] {21};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}








\end{document}
```

I want this style

[image]

Comment: Could you update your title to be more representative of the general request? Perhaps dealing with the placement of nodes in a tree? Otherwise this question is really low-quality (mostly because it is code-only).

Comment: My browser considers every element of the page linked to as potentially malignant and refuses to display any of it. It is sometimes overly paranoid but I have no reason to risk investigating further. If your computer may lack adequate protection, you may wish to exercise particular caution if investigating the contents of the external link further.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but why don't you add more children as you have already started to do?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}\large      
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=100pt}
    \tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
    \tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}} 

    \Tree
    [.\node(yawei){yawei};
    [.\node(muqiu){muqiu}; 
    [.\node(1){1}; [.\node(2){2}; [.\node(3){3}; [.\node(4){4}; ]]]]
    ]   
    ]   

    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={align=center, anchor=center, font=\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries,rectangle,draw,text width=1.4cm,}]
    \foreach \x/\y in {yawei/21, muqiu/22, 1/23, 2/24, 3/25, 4/26}{%
    \node[above= 2mm of \x ] (the\x) {\y};
}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: %%%%%%%%%%%I want this style%%%http://tieba.baidu.com/photo/p?kw=latex&ie=utf-8&flux=1&tid=3730330394&pic_id=e0e432a85edf8db1629a666e0c23dd54574e748c&pn=1&fp=2&see_lz=1

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to add the nodes to the current code is probably to simply position them to the right of 22:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{%
  edge from parent/.style={%
    draw,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- +(14pt,0) |- (\tikzchildnode)},
  },
}
\begin{document}\large
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    grow'=right,
    level distance=100pt,
    execute at begin node=\strut,
    every tree node/.style={anchor=base west},
  ]
  \Tree
  [.\node(yawei){yawei};
    [.\node(muqiu){muqiu}; ]
  ]
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={align=center, anchor=center, font=\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries, rectangle, draw, text width=1.4cm,}]
    \node [above=2mm of muqiu] (thenode) {22};
    \node at (thenode-|yawei) {21};
    \node (next) [right=of thenode] {23};
    \node (one after) [right=of next] {24};
    \node [right=of one after] {25};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: more nodes]

If the diagram doesn't really have branches, it might be easier to position the nodes on a grid or using the `chains` library. However, that would involve rewriting the existing code, which may be more trouble than it is worth if only minor additions are required.